# How to assign one class to be another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I'm trying to create a class called `Theme` in my app. Ideally, what I'd like to be able to do is calling the background color for the current theme by calling: `[[Theme current] background]`.

Now, I wrote a class called `Theme`.

**Theme.h**

```
@interface Theme : NSObject

+ (Theme *)current;

@end
```

**Theme.m**

```
@implementation Theme

static Theme *current = nil;

+ (Theme *)current {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (current == nil) {
            current = ...This is the hard part...
        }
    }
    return current;
}

@end
```

And I also wrote a first theme, a black one.

**Black.h**

```
@interface Theme (Black)

+ (UIColor *)background;

@end
```

**Black.m**

```
@implementation Theme (Black)

+ (UIColor *)background {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

What I'm having difficulties with, is how I can assign `Theme.current` to be `Black`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, here is the singleton pattern for Objective-C (in reference to this is the hard part).

```
@interface Theme : NSObject
+ (Theme *)current;
@end

@implementation Theme

+ (id)current {
    static Theme *current = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        current = [[Theme alloc] init];
    });
    return current;
}

@end
```

Since your app will have a singleton theme, setting the background color is as simple as setting a property. But first we have to add the property. Here is the updated code to do this:

```
@interface Theme : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *background;
+ (Theme *)current;
@end

@implementation Theme

+ (id)current {
    static Theme *current = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        current = [[Theme alloc] init];

        // You can set a default background color or leave it nil.
        current.background = [UIColor cyanColor];
    });
    return current;
}

@end
```

Now to change the theme's background, we just change that property:

```
[Theme current].background = [UIColor blackColor];
// ...
someView.backgroundColor = [Theme current].background;
```

Answer (score 1):

Categories (Eg, `@implementation Theme (Black)` ), are not suitable for your purpose.

You should be using a property (or at least instance variable and getter/setter instance methods).

So you need to have a property of your class like:

```
@interface Theme : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *background;

@end
```

This property will automatically include hidden getter/setter methods, so you don't need to create methods to manage that value (unless you want to override the behaviour, in which case you coule override `- (void)setBackground:(UIColor *)background;` and `- (UIColor *)background;` ).

Now you can access that property from other code by:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [Theme currentTheme].background;
```

If you wish, you could also set that property from your other code by:

```
[Theme currentTheme].background = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Now, if for any reason you wished to maintain multiple themes, you could simply assign them to multiple instance variables or properties of another class like:

```
Theme *themeBlack = [Theme new];
Theme *themeWhite = [Theme new];
themeBlack.background = [UIColor blackColor];
themeWhite.bakcground = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Alternatively, your theme class could include class methods for some standard themes.  Either as normal class methods like:

```
+ (Theme *)blackTheme {
    Theme *theme = [theme new];
    theme.background = [UIColor blackColor];
    return theme;
}

+ (Theme *)whiteTheme {
    Theme *theme = [theme new];
    theme.background = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return theme;
}
```

Or if they were likely to be called frequently, as singleton class methods:

```
+ (Theme *)themeBlack {
    static Theme *themeBlack = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        themeBlack = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return themeBlack;
}

+ (Theme *)themeWhite {
    static Theme *themeWhite = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        themeWhite = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return themeWhite;
}
```

Either way, now your other code from other classes could now be:

```
myViewBlack.background = [Theme themeBlack].background;
myViewWhite.background = [Theme themeWhite].background;
```

Answer (score 1):

@user4992124

The thing that you are trying to achieve cannot be achieved effectively by creating categories. Your below declaration is a Category:

```
@interface Theme (Black)
+ (UIColor *)background;
@end
```

From your question it seems that you are trying to create multiple themes in the application and then there is a possibility that you might switch themes at runtime. **The answer provided by @keithbhunter is a perfect place to start** but then in that case you will have to assign/change multiple properties every time you want to switch the theme. To make it a little easier, you can do something below:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ThemeColors) {    
    ThemeColor_Default,
    ThemeColor_Black,
    ThemeColor_White
};

/* Theme.h */    
@interface Theme : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *backgroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *textColor;
- (instancetype)initWithTheme:(ThemeColors)color;

@end

/* Theme.m */
@implementation Theme

- (instancetype)initWithTheme:(ThemeColors)color {    
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self populateTheme:color];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)populateTheme:(ThemeColors)color {

    switch (color) {
        case ThemeColor_Black:
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            break;
        case ThemeColor_White:
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            break;
        default:
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            self.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            break;
    }
}
@end

/* ThemeManager.h */
@interface ThemeManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Theme *currentTheme;
+ (ThemeManager *)sharedManager;

@end

/* ThemeManager.m */    
@implementation ThemeManager

+ (id)sharedManager {    
    static ThemeManager *sharedManager = nil;    
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;    
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[ThemeManager alloc] init];
        sharedManager.currentTheme = [[Theme alloc] initWithTheme:ThemeColor_Default];
    });    
    return sharedManager;
}
@end

/* Test.h */
@interface Test : UIViewController

@end

/* Test.m */
@implementation Test

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIColor *firstBackgroundColor = [ThemeManager sharedManager].currentTheme.backgroundColor;

    [ThemeManager sharedManager].currentTheme = [[Theme alloc] initWithTheme:ThemeColor_White];
    UIColor *secondBackgroundColor = [ThemeManager sharedManager].currentTheme.backgroundColor;

}
```

Again, this is just one of the ways of doing it. The above approach can always be improved upon. This is to just get you started. I have not executed this code.